# Codeigniter v4 pagination Library

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I found pagination library for Codeigniter 4 on github with this link https://github.com/KejawenLab/CI4Pager . I followed every step, But I get issue on displaying data, I get all the data even I provide a number of limit to be shown per page. But for pagination links it work correct. Please help, how can I limit number of result.

Here is my Code

//controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        helper('paginator');
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
        $paginator = \App\Libraries\Paginator::createFromResult($result, 1, 1);
        return view('page', ['paginator'=> $paginator]);
    }
```

//view

```
    <?php foreach($paginator->getResults() as $row):?>
        <div><?= $row['username'] ?></div>
    <?php endforeach;?>

    <?= ci_pager($paginator, [
            'base_url' => '/vyombo',
            'current_text' => 'Current Page',
            'total_text' => 'Total Records',
        ]);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for an external library. Codeigniter 4 supports pagination out of the box.

You can either paginate query results or manually paginate the array.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html?highlight=pagination

In case you're doing the queries right in the controller, and that is far from ideal. In your case you want to create a model to handle that and then use that model.

```
// In the Controller
public function index()
{
    $userModel = new \App\Models\UserModel();
    $pageModel = new \App\Models\PageModel();

    $data = [
        'users' => $userModel->paginate(10, 'group1'),
        'pages' => $pageModel->paginate(15, 'group2'),
        'pager' => $userModel->pager
    ];

    echo view('users/index', $data);
}
```

Then in your view you can either get the full links or simple links.

```
// In the views:
<?= $pager->links('group1') ?>
<?= $pager->simpleLinks('group2') ?>
```

In case you still want to manually paginate your query you can do something like this:

Lets say you have a query string called page=1. Then you want 10 elements per page.

Just do your query like:

```
$limit = 10;
$offset = 10 * ($_GET['page'] - 1); 

SELECT *
FROM articles
LIMIT $limit, $offset;
```

Then to print the pagination links in your view you would just use:

```
<?= $pager->makeLinks($_GET['page'], $limit, $total) ?>
```

So for your pagination you always need two queries. One that will give you the current page and another one to give you the total results.

Comment: Yes, I used the pager library that way, But I get it difficult to user with query builder. I want to be able to write my sql inside query($sql). But the pager works with Model. How can I do with query() and paginate() data using pager?

Comment: In that case you can make your query setting offset and limit for your pagination. THen you generate the links with this: <?= $pager->makeLinks($page, $perPage, $total) ?>

Comment: Thank you very much! Your advice helped me a lot. I finally get a solution to my issue. I'm posting it to the answer area, I would like to hear any suggestion, advice, and alternatives for my solution if it has a down effect to  the app performance. Thank you  @marcogmonteiro

Answer (score -1):

The solution for the query with multiple table by creating additional view table with
SQL statement ""CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_province_incomes AS ", and set the table property to the model function protected $table = 'default_table'; but replace the table inside method. like  "$this->table = 'view_province_incomes'" which view_province_incomes added automatically to your database and hold your command data.

//model

```
      public function getData()
      {
          //reset table to be used as default
          $this->table = 'view_province_incomes';

          //creating view table to your database to hold the data
            $sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_province_incomes AS ";
          $sql .= "
          SELECT Date, 
          SUM(Income) as Income, 
          SUM(Expense) as Expense, 
          SUM(Income) - SUM(Expense) as Profit 
          FROM ( 
                    SELECT 
                        province_income.date as Date, 
                        province_income.amount as Income, 
                        0 as Expense 
                    FROM province_income
                    LEFT JOIN province ON province.provId = province_income.provId
                    WHERE province_income.provId = 5
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 
                        province_expenses.date as Date, 
                        0 as Income, 
                       province_expenses.amount as Expense 
                    FROM province_expenses
                    LEFT JOIN province ON province.provId = province_expenses.provId
                    WHERE province_expenses.provId = 5 
             ) as t 
          GROUP BY Date
        ";
        
        $this->db->query($sql);
        return $this; //to make easy chaining with the instance
      }
```

//Controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        $data['results'] = $this->model->getData()->asObject()->paginate(4);
        $data['pager']   = $this->model->pager->links();
        return view('Income/index', $data);
    }
```

// Views

```
    <?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        <p> <?= $result->Date ?></p>
        <p> <?= $result->Income ?></p>
        <p> <?= $result->Expense ?></p>
        <p> <?= $result->Profit ?></p>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>

    <!-- pagination links -->
    <?= $pager ?>
```

// Output

```
    +------------+-----------------------------+
    | Date       | Incomes  | Expense | Profit |
    +------------+----------+---------+--------+
    | 2018-06-12 | 10000    | 5000    | 5000   | 
    +------------+----------+---------+--------+
    | 2018-06-14 | 17000    | 9000    | 8000   | 
    +------------+----------+---------+--------+
    | 2018-06-15 | 8000     | 6000    | 2000   |
    +------------------------------------------+
```